# optimization, calculus, minimum area

Tags: calculus, optimization

A covered tank for water is made up of a cuboid whose base is in the form of a square of side
length $2x$ and height $x$ and a right circular cylinder of diameter length $2x$ and height $y$ is placed
on the cuboid .

If the total volume of the tank is $27 cm^3$, find the value of $x$ which makes the
surface area of the tank as minimum as possible

I've get the area $8x^2+\frac{54}x$ then using optimization the answer $x=\frac32$ is it correct?

Comment: can you post a plot please?

Answer (score 1):

Volume of cuboid is $4x^3$

Volume of cylinder is $\pi x^2 y$

$$4x^3+\pi x^2 y=27$$

$$y=\frac{27-4x^3}{\pi x^2}$$

Surface area is $$2( (2x)^2)+4(2x^2) + 2\pi y x =16x^2+2\pi x \frac{27-4x^3}{\pi x^2}=8x^2+\frac{54}{x}$$

To minimize it, we just differentiate with respect to $x$,

$$f'(x)=16x-\frac{54}{x^2}=0$$
$$x^3=\frac{54}{16}=\frac{27}{8}$$

Hence $x=\frac32$

We verify that $$f"(x)=16+\frac{54}{x^3} > 0$$

for $x>0$.

Comment: And also find y for complteness